# Servlet to JSP always passing null value

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I just started using JSP and Servlet, so I encountered a really basic problem. 
I'm trying to make a request from JSP to servlet, where I set a parameter and then forward the answer from servlet back to the jsp.
Here is the code from my JSP:

```
<% String s = (String)request.getAttribute("name");
   out.println(s);
%>
```

Here is my code from servlet:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        request.setAttribute("name", new String("aa"));
        this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
    }
}
```

So in the end, the servlet has the value, but my jsp doesn't.

Comment: Nope, no multiple jsp pages.
Just an index page where I want to get that value that is attributed in the servlet.

Comment: It works if I add getSession to both setAttribute() and getAttribute()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have already declared a String type but you cast it as String also, this is redundant.

```
<% String s = (String)request.getAttribute("name");
   out.println(s);
%>
```

Also, there's a difference between `<%= %>` and `<% %>`. If you want to output the variable into your jsp use the one with the equals (`<%= %>`). The second line of your scriptlet code would also generate an error. The code you write in your servlet doesn't just continue on the JSP, it's not how it works.

if you want to output the name attribute just do this:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("name") %>
```

However since 2010 scriptlets are discouraged (outdated technology).. We use EL and JSTL instead. You should be able to just output the variable like this:

```
${name}
```

In your Servlet all you need to do is this:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  String name = "Jane"; //create a string
  request.setAttribute("name", name); //set it to the request

  RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp"); //the page you want to send your value
  rs.forward(request,response); //forward it

}
```

**EDIT**

You asked,

> Is there a way to trigger the servlet let s say on a click of a button
>   or something like that?

Yes, there are multiple ways to do it and it really depends on how you want it setup. An easy way to trigger the servlet on a button click is like this. *(Assuming you have a servlet mapped onto `/Testing`):

```
<a href="/Testing">Trigger Servlet<a>
```

Another way could be with a form:

```
<form action="Testing" method="get">
<input type="hidden" name="someParameterName" value="you can send values like this">
<button type="submit">Do some magic</button>
</form>
```

There's also AJAX (which involves javascript). But this is fairly advanced and i don't recommend doing it until you are familiar with normal **synchronous** http behaviour.

Comment: Great thanks! :) 
But my problem is still there :/ for some reason, i still get "null" value in the jsp

Comment: how are you going to the jsp? are you just visiting the jsp directly?

Comment: I'm guessing that's what you're doing because that's the only reason i see that you are getting null.  You need to run the servlet doGet method before being able to pass the value to the jsp. What is the url mapping for your servlet?

Comment: Yes. 
I'm expecting just to enter the jsp page and get the value from servlet.

Comment: I also tried entering servlet first and then go back to jsp but it did not work.

Comment: It seems to work if i add getSession() to both getAttribute and setAttribute

Comment: yeah it doesn't work like that, you can't just visit a jsp and expect to get values from the servlet without running the servlet. You have to enter the url for the servlet (which is mapped onto the doGet method) and then the servlet redirects your page to the JSP, and then you will be able to see the name value

Comment: so for example... imagine your servlet is called `Test` and it has a url-mapping for `/Testing`...  To be able to see that name variable in your jsp file, you need to visit the url : `http//localhost:8080/Testing` (or whatever your port and project configuration is specified as)... When you type in that url, the servlet will run and it will redirect you (forward) to the jsp page where the name variable is displayed. You cannot access the variable by just visiting your .jsp file directly. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: The reason why you are seeing the variable when you use the Session object is because sessions persist for the whole duration of whatever your project has specified the session limit as. Sessions are usually used to store information about what user is currently logged in and this kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, it does make sense. Thanks a lot!:)

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the servlet let s say on a click of a button or something like that?

Comment: Yes you can do that, check my edited answer, i give you two examples where you can trigger the servlet.

Comment: Waw! Great! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: no problemo! If you have any problems/questions about anything else java/servlet/jsp related feel free to reach out.

Comment: I don't have the reputation to chat yet. :( But I have one more question. 
Let's say we have a jsp file with a select box in it. How can I get in the servlet the selected index of that box?

Comment: Hey sorry slow reply. I meant through something else maybe. (My contact details on my profile.) As long as you have a name attribute on your select box input you can get the value in the servlet with String selectvalue = request.getParameter ("nameOfSelect");

Answer (score 1):

Try without a writer, you don't want two writing contexts to a single response. You are also not using it:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    request.setAttribute("name", new String("aa"));
    this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call the request dispatcher method using request object. This is how you do it :

```
RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
rs.forward(request,response);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either.
My problem is that when i go into the servlet page, i get the "aa" value there, but when I go back to jsp, it is still null.